# Oracle Procedure error: numeric or value error: number precision too large?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Here's the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GetBestSellingMovieByTimeId(timeId IN NUMBER) IS
  movieName Movie.Name%type;
  saleValue Sales.SaleValue%type;
BEGIN
SELECT * INTO movieName, salevalue FROM (
  SELECT m.Name, SUM(s.SaleValue) AS TotalSales 
    FROM Sales s 
    INNER JOIN Movie m ON s.MovieId = m.MovieId 
    WHERE s.TimeId = timeId 
    GROUP BY m.Name ORDER BY TotalSales DESC
  ) WHERE ROWNUM = 1;
  dbms_output.put_line(movieName ||', ' || saleValue);
END;
/
exec GetBestSellingMovieByTimeId(2);
```

Here's the error:

```
Error starting at line 190 in command: exec GetBestSellingMovieByTimeId(2) 
Error report: 
 ORA-06502: PL/SQL:numeric or value error: number precision too large
 ORA-06512: at "CM420B17.GETBESTSELLINGMOVIEBYTIMEID", line 5 
 ORA-06512: at line 1
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
 *Cause:    
 *Action:
```

TimeID is a NUMBER(2,0) FK on a Sales table. Passing the number 2 to the procedure shouldn't be out of range of the NUMBER(2,0) data type.

Why does this procedure think the IN parameter is too large?

Comment: Did you try running the query inside the function with the parameter on Developer or SQL*Plus? Looks to me like your saleValue variable is too short for the result.

Comment: The error is at line 5 --> SELECT * INTO movieName, salevalue FROM ... What is a type of saleValue Sales.SaleValue%type ? The procedure is trying to assign to this variable a result of SUM( xxx ), which is of type NUMERIC.

Comment: That was exactly the problem. The NUMBER field for SaleValue was too small to hold the SUM of the sale values. Thanks @tilly31 and kordirko, problem resolved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query selects `SUM(s.SaleValue)` into a variable `saleValue` defined as  `Sales.SaleValue%type`.

Normally using the `%type` syntax is good practice, but only when it matches the assigned value.  If `Sales.SaleValue` is defined with scale and precision it is quite likely that a SUM() of that column will blow the bounds of that definition.  As appears to be the case here.